# Logarithmic scale with imshow and "extent"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am having issues making a plot with a logarithmic y axis using imshow. My relevant code is as follows:

```
plt.imshow(power[channel], extent=(0,600,1,45), \
origin='lower', cmap='jet', aspect='auto', vmin=0, vmax=0.00025)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show(block=False)
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image: Wavelet plot]

My problem is that I need the "extent" parameter because otherwise the y axis labeling is incorrect in my case. However it seems that imshow (which includes the "extent" parameter) does not allow logarithmic axis scaling. Adding the line

```
plt.yscale('log')
```

gives me the warning "Images are not supported on non-linear axes."

Is there a way I can get logarithmic y axis scaling while keeping the "extent" function?

Comment: May I encourage you [against using jetmap](http://bids.github.io/colormap/)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you'll have solved this by now, but I wanted to post an answer in case any one comes looking (like me). I was having a very similar problem trying to do `plt.imshow()` with a log y-axis: using extent was giving me the wrong axis labels.

My 'solution' was to use `plt.pcolormesh()` instead of `plt.imshow()`. You can pass an x and y meshgrid to this alongside your image and you can then set your log axes as I illustrate below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the x coordinate
x = np.linspace(0, 50)
# create logarithmic y coordinate
y = np.logspace(1, 4)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# create random image data to use
im_data = np.random.rand(x.size, y.size)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, im_data)

# make y axis logarithmic
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image: script output]

You can see it handles the log-axes nicely. Hopefully this helps you or anyone else who comes looking (I realise this doesn't answer your exact question but its a straight forward work-around).